# get nearby users using spatial index mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing, spatial

I have more than 20K users in the user's table and I have implemented a query that shows 10 nearby users at one time. I have tried this

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(42.29297046302411) ) * COS( RADIANS( User.lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS(User.long) - RADIANS(-108.7299657985568)) + SIN(RADIANS(42.29297046302411)) * SIN( RADIANS(User.lat)))) AS distance from user as User GROUP BY distance HAVING distance < 100 LIMIT 10
```

This query is slow and if I do Explain then
[image]
My table structure looks like this

[image]

Now In order to make it faster, I did some research and find out about `spatial index`. So I did this

Afterward, I added new column with the name of `polygon` and added (long,lat) with datatype `point`

[image]
[image]

And used query this

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id,first_name, st_distance_sphere(polygon, POINT(73.1270688, 31.4554433)) AS distance
FROM user
WHERE ST_Distance_Sphere(polygon, POINT(73.1270688, 31.4554433)) < 100
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

The result is the same. The query going all through records that are more than 20K. May I know what I am doing wrong and how can make this query faster

[image]

My Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `first_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `last_name` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 `lat` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `long` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `polygon` point NOT NULL,
 `created` datetime NOT NULL,

 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `lat` (`lat`,`long`),
 SPATIAL KEY `polygon` (`polygon`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22431 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Are you using a "polygon" to approximate the shape of a human?  Seems like you just want the distance between two POINTs.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE user`.  Please provide text, not images.  I am hoping to see `SPATIAL (polygon)` as the first step in speeding up the query.

Comment: @RickJames I just want the query to speed up and want to implement indexing. So If it can be achieved without polygon I am okay with that

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ...,
        ST_Distance_Sphere(center_point, item_point) AS meters
     FROM table
     WHERE ... (any filtering)
       AND st_contains(st_geomfromtext('Polygon((...))'),  -- The bounding box is encoded as a 'square'
                       sp_point)
     HAVING meters <= ...
     ORDER BY distance ASC, id ASC
     LIMIT ...
```

Discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Comment: can you please write full query by seeing my table?

Comment: What's a likely distance?  Perhaps 10K meters?  The MBRContains uses the spatial index, and the polygon is (most easily) a rectangle based on 1 degree of latitude is 111K meters and 1 degree of longitude is that divided by the cosine of the latitude.

Comment: Yes you can write it with 10K meters

Comment: The polygon would be lat +/- 0.05 and lng +/- 0.05 * cos(radians(lat)).  0.05 of latitude equates to about 5.5km.

Comment: Example:  `st_geomfromtext('POLYGON ((16.2 48.1, 16.4 48.1, 16.4 48.2, 16.2 48.2, 16.2 48.1))'`